# Generate Bar Code CI 39 with CoreImage

Tags: swift, barcode, barcode-printing, code128, code39

I need to implement a barcode generator (I don't want a barcode reader). So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542240/how-to-generate-a-barcode-from-a-string-in-swift) and it works great for the Code 128 symbology.

How can I generate a Code 39 symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with the CoreImage framework I am unable to find any reference to Code 39 barcode generation in the documentation, however it has been noted that the documentation is incomplete at times.

According to [this blog post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2015/06/core-image-barcode-erratum/) you can determine which filters are available by running the following code:

```
NSArray *b = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryGenerator];
NSLog(@"%@", b);
```

You can further determine the input parameters for any given filter as follows:

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAztecCodeGenerator"];
NSDictionary *attributes = [filter attributes];
NSLog(@"%@", attributes);
```

This will help you to determine whether Code 39 support has crept into a recent release of the framework and how to drive it if this should be the case.