# Barcode Not Generating

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, barcode, cifilter

I'm using the below code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542447/6618757) to generate a Code128 barcode from a string. For some reason it's not woking. The function does returns an image but I'm not able to see it in the simulator after assigning the image to a `UIImageView`.

```
 class Barcode {

    class func fromString(string : String) -> UIImage? {

        let data = string.data(using: .ascii)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator")
        filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

        return UIImage(ciImage: (filter?.outputImage)!)
    }

}
```

Have imported `CoreImage`. Function call:

```
let barcodeImg = Barcode.fromString(string: number)
self.userBarcodeImageView.image = barcodeImg
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

**Solved**

Substituted the code for this function, found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799223/6618757)

```
func generateBarcode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {

let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICode128BarcodeGenerator") {
    filter.setDefaults()
    //Margin
    filter.setValue(7.00, forKey: "inputQuietSpace")
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    //Scaling
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)

    if let output = filter.outputImage?.applying(transform) {
        let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
        let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)!
        let rawImage:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)

        //Refinement code to allow conversion to NSData or share UIImage. Code here:
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240395/uiimage-created-from-cgimageref-fails-with-uiimagepngrepresentation
        let cgimage: CGImage = (rawImage.cgImage)!
        let cropZone = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(rawImage.size.width), height: Int(rawImage.size.height))
        let cWidth: size_t  = size_t(cropZone.size.width)
        let cHeight: size_t  = size_t(cropZone.size.height)
        let bitsPerComponent: size_t = cgimage.bitsPerComponent
        //THE OPERATIONS ORDER COULD BE FLIPPED, ALTHOUGH, IT DOESN'T AFFECT THE RESULT
        let bytesPerRow = (cgimage.bytesPerRow) / (cgimage.width  * cWidth)

        let context2: CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: cWidth, height: cHeight, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: cgimage.bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

        context2.draw(cgimage, in: cropZone)

        let result: CGImage  = context2.makeImage()!
        let finalImage = UIImage(cgImage: result)

        return finalImage

    }
}

return nil
}
```

Got it to work.

Comment: Make sure your image view is not hidden or in  front by setting any background color.

Comment: the `UIImageView` background colour is default, its not hidden..

Comment: Try any other image form assest and check is it visible or not

Comment: yes, its assigns image from Assets properly and its visible.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue. After long research find below solution.

Please ensure your `imageView` height and width should be an Integer number. If `imageView` height and width is float number then it will not genrate `barcode` image.

Comment: the height of the `UIImageView` is fixed 251x85, not float number